# Core Text - How to grow UIView?

Tags: iphone, resize, core-text

I am using Core Text (for text bleed/wrap effect). Since the body of the `UIView` has to grow with the text and images put onto the view, I want my `UIView` to adjust its height accordingly.

I tried `sizeToFit` (on my `UIView`) to adjust its height according to its contents. However, the `UIView` doesn't increase its height, although it can decrease it alright.

This is how my hierarchy of the `UIView` looks like:

> [UITextView]
>
> [UIImageView] (can be 0 or many)

How could I make my `UIView` adjust its height according to the contents it has?

Comment: As you will shortly find, writing your own custom view to handle this sort of thing is a terrible idea. Then you will use [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html). Once you do this, you can simply call `setContentSize` and everything will work out very well for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There are 2 issues with the solution though. 1->How do I dynamically grow the `UIScrollView`? 2->Can I call `setNeedsDisplay` (on ScrollView) more frequently (because the text on the scrollview will not move as quick as the `UIImageViews`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am putting the text in a `UITextView` and then displaying it in the `UIView` (using CoreText), so I basically set the height of my `UIView` as:

> (height of textview) + (height of images)

Although it isn't an elegant solution but atleast it works alright.

PS: a better solution might be to add a right proportion of height and width (since the text wraps around the image).